# From python Counter dictionary to nd numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I know this is a very classic question, but after going through many posts, I decided to bring it back, without being able to find an elegant solution for something seemingly basic.
   The problem:

I have a Counter dictionary from a large data set, with meaningful integer keys, and integer occurrences:

```
co = Counter({8046: 1360, 10046: 1248, 11046: 1024})
```

And I *simply* want to end up with a basic integer array:

```
a = np.array([[8046,1360],[10046,1248],[11046,1024]])
```

The specificity of this problem (or the absence of specificity) is that I have integer keys, and I don't need a structured array. The following

```
dtype = dict(names = ['id','data'], formats=['i8','i8'])
array = np.fromiter(iter(co.items()), dtype=dtype)
```

is not quite satisfying, ending up with

```
a = [(8046, 1360) (10046, 1248) (11046, 1024)]
```

Is it just a question of dtype? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could turn it into a list of list before converting to a numpy array:

```
>>> np.array(list(co.items()))
array([[ 8046,  1360],
       [10046,  1248],
       [11046,  1024]])
```

Comment: Yes! I lost myself in these types and iterators, forgetting the basics. So the combination np.array(list()) avoid us to specify dtypes. Now I wander why 'np.fromiter' is so rigid about it, but I guess I'm just missing something. Thanks @kennytm .

Comment: If I'm not wrong, a simple `co.items()` should suffice instead of `list(co.items())`.

Comment: @JRodDynamite `np.array(co.items())` creates an array of objects instead of 2D array. `array(dict_items([(8046, 1360), (10046, 1248), (11046, 1024)]), dtype=object)`